# Convert double list objects in object list to string

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I am having a list of data objects. Each data object has a `resultList` of double elements which can also be null.

I want pull out this `resultList` of the data object and store them seperately in a string list:

```
List<List<String>> ar_List = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dataList.get(i).getResultList().size(); j++) {
        ar_List.add(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j).toString());
    }
}
```

However I still get an error at `ar_List.add(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j).toString());`

Any recommendations how to write the List Objects into `ar_List`?

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: `ar_List` should contain `List<String>`, not `String`.

Comment: Why are you adding a `String` when you should be adding `List<String>`?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun what do you mean? `ar_List` contains `List<List<String>>`...

Comment: @user2051347 `ar_List` is a list of `List<String>`. You are trying to push a `String` as evident by `dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j).toString()`

Comment: @user2051347 No. It's a "list of list that contain Strings".

Comment: @Rakesh Thx for your answer! Please explain further. I do not understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the data is null because calling `toString()` on a null object causes a NPE. And you need to get the `List<String>` and not `List<List<String>>`

```
if(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j) != null) {
       ar_List.get(i).add(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j).toString());
}
```

In order to check for null lists either filter the parent list for null objects or change the for condition.

`for(in j = 0; j < dataList.get(i).getResultList().size(); dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j)==null?j+=2:j++)`

This jumps over the next row if the next row is null. But the better would be to clean the list.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I am also getting the NPE at `    for (int j = 0; j < dataList.get(i).getResultList().size(); j++) {` because one list is null. Is there a way to prevent from stopping iterating over the list?

Comment: Either clear the list from null objects or change the for condition.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I cannot clear the condition... Any recommendation how to change the for condition?

Comment: `for(in j = 0; j < dataList.get(i).getResultList().size(); dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j)==null?j+=2:j++)`
This jumps over the next row if the next row is null. But the better would be to clean the list.

Comment: Please add this to your answer! So that I can accept it!

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
ar_List.add(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j).toString());
```

with

```
ar_List.get(i).add(dataList.get(i).getResultList().get(j).toString());
```